# Многопроцеcсорность в python и telebot

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

Я пишу своего первого бота на `telebot` и у меня возникли проблемы с многопроцессорностю. Есть файл `main` и есть несколько файлов которых нужно запустить одновременно.
Но я не могу их как-то запустить , буду очень благодарен если поможете , заранее благодарю.

Comment: Что хранится в Ваших `main` и других файлах?

Comment: @AlexZab Main запускает init .В остальных записаны файлы для команд бота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй модуль multiprocessing

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
def start_bot(token)
    """
        тут функция, которая стартуе бота
    """
    pass 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bots_token = ['token1', 'token2']
    for token in bots_token:
        mp.set_start_method('fork')
        mp.Process(target=f, args=(token)).start()
```

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться , что за `token1` и `token2` ?

Comment: токены с помощью которых вы авторизуетесь в телеграмме. bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')

Answer (score 1):

Я Вам рекомендую записать все команды бота в один файл как функции и запускать эти функции с помощью `threading`, к примеру -

```
import telebot
import time
import threading

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")
    time.sleep(86400)
threading.Thread(target = hello, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Помощь!")
    time.sleep(3600)
threading.Thread(target = help, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['else'])
def else(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Другое!")
    time.sleep(60)
threading.Thread(target = else, args = (1,), daemon = True).start()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Как вам идея замены кортежа списком `(1,)` -> `[1]`? :)

Comment: Зачем? Можете объяснить?

Comment: Просто вкусовщина :) Мне кажется это выглядит красивее для одного элемента -- нет запятой, да и в целом круглые скобки в аргумент функции, где уже есть круглые скобки может путать